# Переход к другой функции telebot

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

Подскажите что делаю не так

```
def handle_excel_file(message):
    # Check file.xlsx
    if message.document:
        user_id = message.chat.id
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        file_path = file_info.file_path

        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_path)

        # File_name = user_id
        file_name = f"{message.from_user.id}.xlsx"

        # # Сохраняем файл на сервере
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

        
        print(message)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Файл успешно загружен и сохранен.")
        tax = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь отправь мне сумму налога")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(tax, get_taxes)


    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибка! Отправленный документ не является файлом.")


def get_taxes(tax):
    print(f"тут {tax}")
    taxes = tax.text
    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''UPDATE users SET taxes = ?''', (taxes,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь отправь мне сумму штрафов")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_penalty)
```

бот не переходит к функции `def get_taxes(tax):`

Comment: Должен переходить. А вы уверены, что у вас `if` отрабатывает, а не `else`?

Comment: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибка! Отправленный документ не является файлом.") в else бот должен был отправить сообщение, но так как не отправляет, то получается отрабатывает if

Comment: А сообщение выводит про налог? А ошибок никаких не вылазит?

Comment: В этом и проблема, сообщение выводит, но дальше просто тишина. Ни ошибок, ни пребывания кодов. просто в функцию не переходит и все. Делал дополнительную функцию, просто ее вызывал def handler(message), туда вставлял bot.send... и bot.register... но и в этот раз в другую функцию не переходило